# make asp.net MVC 4 views compiled / give errors on compilation, not only on first access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, compiler-errors

I have a Asp.Net MVC 4 View (Razor), which includes a model like below:

```
@model Project.Models.TestModel
```

The problem is that if I go the project, and rename `TestModel` to `TestModel2`, and I click on rebuild project, no errors are given.  If I open up the `.cshtml` file directly, then I do get the error there.

Can you enforce such errors to be given immediately at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open *.Web.csproj file and change this:

```
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

to true